# using a list file to cut and move specific files to another directory

Tags: python, shutil

here is my code

```
import os
import shutil
x_file = open(os.path.join('C:\\Users\\_\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\Part 7 Sketches', "output.txt"), "r")  
for image in x_file:
    v=str.strip(image)
    shutil.move('C:\\Users\\_\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\Part 7 Sketches\\'+v, 'C:\\Users\\_\\Pictures\\New')
```

I want to use the list file (output text) to search through the directory and move the selected pictures to a new directory.  When I do this I get an error front that say

```
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\_\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\Part 7 Sketches\\001'
```

The file exists however... any help is appreciated

Comment: It tells you that the file doesn't exist, and as I don't know what is in `output.txt` I can't help you.

Comment: output.txt is just a text file listing some images, they do exist in the source

Comment: Well look at what it tells you: `/path/to/dir/001`. Have you tried adding the extensions? Looks like it is thinking it is a `dir`.

Comment: yes that ffixed it, now the folder new is not being made, its moving the files but not to a newly created folder...

Comment: Sounds like another opportunity to ask a question!

Comment: haha why wont the folder new be made...do I need to make it beforehand to move the images